# Convert base64 string to WordPress attachment uploads multiple images instead of a single one

Tags: php, wordpress, base64, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to convert a base64 string to an image file and upload it into WordPress media library.

It seems like the code is working, but, for some reason, every time I call this function it uploads the same image multiple times.. I wonder what am I doing wrong and what I need to change in order to fix it.

This is my code:

```
<?php 

class Catalog
{

    public function uploadBase64Image()
    {
        //Base 64 string example
        $base64_img = include 'testbase64.php'; 

        $upload_dir  = wp_upload_dir();
        $upload_path = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $upload_dir['path']) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $title = "test"; 
        $image_parts = explode(";base64,",$base64_img);
        $decoded = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
        $mime = substr($base64_img, 11, 4);
        $mime = str_replace(';', '', $mime);
        $filename = $title . '.' . $mime;
        $file_type = 'image/' . $mime;
        $hashed_filename = md5($filename . microtime()) . '_' . $filename;
        $upload_file = file_put_contents($upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded);

        $attachment = [
            'post_mime_type' => $file_type,
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($hashed_filename)),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'guid' => $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($hashed_filename)
        ];

        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $hashed_filename);

        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $hashed_filename);
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

        return $attach_id;

    }
```

I'm including this class using `require_once` in my theme's `functions.php` file and using it this way:

```
 function testCatalog()
 {
    if(!is_admin()) {
        $catalog = new Catalog();
        return $catalog->uploadBase64Image();
    }
 }
 add_action('init', 'testCatalog');
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks is advance!

Comment: When you say "every time I call this function it uploads the same image multiple times", do you mean that whenever you visit URL on your WordPress site it runs multiple times?